# what is the named constructor equivalent of the literal constructor for the Range class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

somewhat new to rails. I am working through the exercises on 4.4.1 in Michael Hartl's learn rails tutorial and i'm a bit unclear as to what the named constructor for the class Range is

when i type the literal constructor in the console it returns the appropriate value

```
(1..10)
=>1..10
```

but when i try the named constructor

```
Range.new(1..10)
```

i receive an error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
    from (irb):104:in `initialize'
    from (irb):104:in `new'
```

Ive tried adding many types of extra arguments i.e

```
Range.new(1)..Range.new(10)
Range.new(1)..(10)
etc..
```

But I'm always met with an argument error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

should be a hint that you need at least 2 parameters :

```
Range.new(1,10)
```

The 3rd parameter is to specify if the last element of the range is excluded or not :

```
Range.new(1,10,false).to_a
# equivalent to (1..10)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Range.new(1,10,true).to_a
# equivalent to (1...10)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

See the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html).

## Your code

```
Range.new(1..10)
```

This is still [`Range#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html) with just one parameter : an already initialized Range!

```
Range.new(1)..Range.new(10)
```

This is a `a..b` syntax, so it tries to initialize a Range between `a` and `b`. What is `a`? `Range.new(1)`, which isn't defined, because it only has 1 parameter. You cannot create a Range between 2 Ranges anyway :

```
Range.new(1,2)..Range.new(4,5)
#=> ArgumentError: bad value for range

Range.new(1)..(10)
```

Same problem as before. Only 1 parameter for `Range.new` and this would be a Range between a Range and an Integer!

Comment: According to the timestamps, you beat me by 3 seconds...:)

Comment: You didn't have to remove your answer, but I'll do it next time I post a similar answer shortly after yours!

Comment: I see! The documentation was a bit confusing as it used Xs.new(3)..Xs.new(6)   to construct a new range  but makes sense now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can read documentation with `ri` command

```
ri Range.new
```

Which prints

```
= Range.new

(from ruby site)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Range.new(begin, end, exclude_end=false)    -> rng

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Constructs a range using the given begin and end. If the exclude_end parameter
is omitted or is false, the rng will include the end object; otherwise, it
will be excluded.
```

NB, `ri` works both on the terminal commandline and inside the `pry` repl.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the help.